# Multiple consumers with same group id

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, partition

I am a beginner in Kafka. I understood that multiple consumers with same group id can't consume messages from the same partition in a topic. I am wondering what may happen if multiple Kafka consumers from a consumer group read the same message from a partition and why its a bad thing.

.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously processing the same record multiple times is almost never intended, but it more comes down to offset management

If multiple consumers in a group read the same message and commit the offset of the message to indicate it's successfully been processed, then the final commit (the slowest consumer) always wins. Meanwhile, other consumers would've already continued processing other data.

When that happens, and any consumer client restarts, it would need to rewind to the last committed offset, despite having already processed messages afterwards

Comment: OneCricketeer, Thanks a lot for explaining this clearly 